# How to like/unlike and subscribe a YouTube video from a android app

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I'm trying to create a YouTube video android app.Currently there no issue to play video and fetch a playlist because there are sample for this.But I'm unable to find  any good reference to  **like/unlike and subscribe events in YouTube**.

So How to like/unlike and subscribe a YouTube video from a android app ?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it in your own application.

You will have to redirect the user of your application to the channel he wants to subscribe to through the YouTube App.

You can use this method from the YouTube API : `createChannelIntent` ([link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeIntents#createChannelIntent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String))). From there, your user will be able to subscribe to the channel, as it will be opened into the YouTube App.

Make sure that the YouTube App is installed before ([link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeIntents#isYouTubeInstalled(android.content.Context))) ! :)

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the YouTube Data apis. [Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate) you can read how to like/dislike a video.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use this code:

```js
// Sample Java code for user authorization

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;

import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTubeScopes;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.*;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class ApiExample {

    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "API Sample";

    /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
    System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/java-youtube-api-tests");

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    /** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     *
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
     * at ~/.credentials/drive-java-quickstart
     */
    private static final Collection<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList("YouTubeScopes.https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl YouTubeScopes.https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner");

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = ApiExample.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader( in ));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
        flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        System.out.println(
            "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized API client service, such as a YouTube
     * Data API client service.
     * @return an authorized API client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static YouTube getYouTubeService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new YouTube.Builder(
        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        YouTube youtube = getYouTubeService();

        try {
            HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            parameters.put("id", "E6UTz_Doic8");
            parameters.put("rating", "like");

            YouTube.Videos.Rate videosRateRequest = youtube.videos().rate(parameters.get("id").toString(), parameters.get("rating").toString());
            videosRateRequest.execute();


        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : " + e.getDetails().getMessage());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

can be more complete later,
[This](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/)